# setIndeterminate programatically in android not working in onresume

Tags: android, progress-bar

i have to xml file to show different progressbar drawable

xml_progressbar_green:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loadgreen"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
```

xml_progressbar_blue:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loadblue"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
```

how to change progressbar drawable duaring runtime?

i want to change this drawable by changing the application's theme

i ve tried these codes in onResume() but it didn't work

why i can not change this by coding?
if i set  indeterminate during design it works fine but when i want to set it in runtime it cant set the value

```
progressbar = new android.widget.ProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);


progressbar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_progress_indeterminate_green));
```

is there any properties missed that should i set in codeing?

thanks in advance...

Comment: how do you insert your progress bar in your activity?

Comment: i added through xml and set the properties and then from code i want to change the peroper drawable for it

Comment: If that is the case, user `findViewById` to reference your progress bar, dont create a new one

Comment: Did you ever solve this?